# Quitar barra derecha que muestra codigo en visual studio code

Tags: interfaz-gráfica, vscode

uso el editor de codigo visual studio code. Cada vez que edito un archivo me aparece la siguiente barra al lado derecho
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero quitar esa barra. Quien sabe como ?

Comment: pestaña view, opcion ---> show minimap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

básicamente es un mini mapa de tu código si quieres ocultarlo simplemente desactiva lo siguiente desde la opción ver:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si te sientes más cómodo editando el archivo settings.json se puede añadir la sigueinte línea: "editor.minimap.enabled": false